# Proof that the probability $P(X<Y) = 0.5$ for two iid variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm struggling to prove analytically that for two iid (independent and identically distributed) random variables $ P(X<Y) = 0.5$ for any distribution. I'm able to do it by direct integration on specific distributions, but not in the general usecase.

Comment: It's not true for arbitrary distributions. If there are point masses, such as for any discrete distribution, the nonzero probability that $X=Y$ throws this off. Perhaps there should be additional restrictions?

Comment: Sorry its in the case of continuous distribution, basically it just come from another thread (that I lost) in the specific case of a continous uniform, and people started arguing that its valid for any distribution (which makes sense by intuiton, symmetry)

Comment: Hint: First show that $P(X = Y) = 0$. To accomplish then, first show that $X,Y$ being iid with a pdf implies that $(X,Y)$ has a pdf. (You can explicitly write down what the pdf is in terms of the pdf of the distribution of $X$.)

Comment: $(x,y) \to (y,x)$ is a probability-preserving transformation of the sample space.  Thus $P(X>Y) = P(Y>X)$.  And if $P(X=Y)=0$ then each must be $1/2$.